# HOW TO OUTPUT DATA GOT FROM combined queryset IN DJANGO TEMPLATE (html file)?

Tags: django, model, filtering, django-queryset

Am having a problem. And l request for your Help.

Am having 3 apps in Django project

- action
- adventure
- others

`#action/ models.py

....

```
class Action(models.Model):

    name=models.Charfield()

    os= models.Charfield( choices=OS)....
```

#adventure/models.py

....

```
class Adventure(models.Model):

     name=models.Charfield()

     os= models.Charfield( choices=OS)....
```

#Others/views.py

```
from itertools import chain

from action.models import Action

from adventure.models import Adventure

def windows_games(request):

    win_action = Action.objects.filter(os='windows')

    win_adventure = Adventure.objects.filter(os='windows')

    combined_list = list(chain(win_action,win_adventure))

    context = ['combined_list':combined_list,] 

         return render(request, 'others/os/windows_game.html' , context)
```

#others/os/windows_game.html

```
.....

<div class="container">

 <img src="{{combined_list.game_pic}}">

 <p>{{combined_list.name}}</p>
```

1). I need to correct me in #others/ views.py  if there is any mistake done.

2). I would like to know how to know how to write the tag that outputs the results in #others/os/windows_game.html because I tried that but outputs nothing.

And l would like to be in form of,              #`{{combined_list.game_pic}}`, etc

It needed to display all items created in those models to display in **windows_game** page, after filtering those that only follow in **category** of *windows*.

I tried creating the context but there was no output results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my friend here helped me like that bellow and it worked for me
*#Windows_game.html*

```
{% for game in combined_list %}
<p> {{game.game_name}}</p>
......
{% endfor %}
```